# Only show the first name from the same variable

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a variable in PHP:

```
<p><?php echo  $this->userInfo->name;?></p>
```

This outputs their first name and surname (i.e. Joe Bloggs)

I want to only show their first name and the first character of their last name (i.e. Joe B)

I can show the first character of their first name and hide the rest by doing the following in CSS:

```
p {
    visibility: hidden;
}
p::first-letter {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I'm thinking I could use a function in PHP, along the lines of:

```
function abbreviateName($this->userInfo->name) {

      if($this->userInfo->name == "")
    return "";

 $tmp = explode(" ", $this->userInfo->name, 2)
      if(count($tmp)<=1) {
      return ucwords($tmp[0]).".";
 } else {
    $fn = ucwords($tmp[0]);
    $ln = ucwords(substr($tmp[1],0,1);
    return $fn.". ".$ln.".";
   }
}
```

But that's not working

Comment: Can you not use string operations in PHP?

Comment: “But that's not working” — what does that mean? Do you get an error? Does it not give the output you want? Do you get a blank screen because of the missing semicolon after the `explode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've come up with a nice and simple solution:

```
[$first_name, $last_name] = explode(' ', $this->userInfo->name);

echo  $first_name . " " . substr($last_name, 0, 1);
```

Which seems to do the job nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's always exactly one space, you can take the substring of the string from the start to one after the index of the space.

```php
substr($this->userInfo->name, 0, strpos($this->userInfo->name, " ") + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just write function in PHP to format the name before it is `echo`'d out?

```php
function regexMatcher($text, $pattern) {
  $__matches = [];
  $__is_match = preg_match($pattern, $text, $__matches);
  return $__is_match ? $__matches : null;
}

function formatUsername($username) {
  $matches = regexMatcher($username, "/^(\w+\s\w)\w*$/");
  echo is_array($matches) ? $matches[1] : $username;
}

$userInfo = new stdClass();
$userInfo->name = "Joe Bloggs";

echo formatUsername($userInfo->name); // "Joe B"
```